# $f>0$ on a non-null measure set then there exist a constant $c>0$ and a non-null measure $A$ set such that $f\geq c$ on A

Tags: calculus, probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real random variable such that $X>0$ on a non-null measure set $B$. Then there exist a constant $c>0$ and a non-null measure set $A\subseteq B$ such that $X\geq c$ on $A$.

Is this statement true? Intuitively, I think this is true, but I am not able to provide a proof. If it is not true, can you give a counter-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_n = \{\omega \in B: X(\omega)\geqslant \frac1n\}$, then $B=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$ for all $n$ so by continuity from below we have
$$
0<\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(A_n).
$$
Take $c=\frac{\mathbb P(B)}2$ and choose $N$ such that $0<c<\mathbb P(A_n)$ for $n\geqslant N$. Then in particular $A_N\subset B$ with $\mathbb P(A_N)>0$ and $X\geqslant \frac1N$ on $A_N$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is true and a basic fact.

If $X > 0$ on $A$, then you need to use the fact that the sets $A_n := \{\omega \in A : X \geq 1/n\}$ are an increasing sequence of measurable subsets of $A$ with the property that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = A$.